# How to (simulate) bonemeal with commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to run a command/series of commands where I can specify an x y and z coordinate of a block and then bonemeal will be *used* on that block.

By *used* I mean:

- Have the same Fertilizer effects described [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bone_Meal#Fertilizer)
- Create new plants in the same way as is described [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bone_Meal#Creating_new_plants)
- If the coordinates are of a block where bonemeal cannot be used, e.g. air, the command should do nothing

I would like to be able to run this command through any method which can be achieved both manually and **automated** i.e. run in a command block. For instance, 3 trigger commands for x, y, and z and then a run trigger command; summoning a specific entity at the coordinates; etc...

*Note: I am running* `1.14.3`

Answer (score 3):

There is no "bonemeal command". You need to place a dispenser with bonemeal in it and activate it.

Comment: I've tested creating a dispenser with bonemeal that has triggered blockstate set to true however this does not activate the dispenser and use the bonemeal. Is the only other solution to create a dispenser next the the block and then create a redstone block next to the dispenser? If I wanted this to be silent would cloning away the blocks and then replacing them after bonemealing work?

Comment: You can use /data modify on blocks right? Don't crops have an "age" you can set, and you can manually create the particles, so you don't need to actually apply bonemeal: you can just mimic it?

Comment: Of course you could completely reprogram all the features of bonemeal with commands, including on grass blocks, with biome detection using advancements and the corresponding flower types and so on and so on. But the question didn't sound like that was the plan. You can also try setting "triggered" to true one tick after placing the dispenser, maybe that works. Otherwise, yes, dispenser and redstone block.

Comment: Oh, of course, it's a block state, not a tile entity field. So you can only change it by replacing the block. I tried it anyway and of course it didn't work. So the redstone block is the solution.